# TypeError: date.getHours is not a function?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: date.getHours is not a function

when trying to use `.getHours` and I'm not sure why. This is the code I'm using:

```
import React from "react";
import "../Nav/Nav.css";
import Date from "./Date";

function NavBar() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hrs = date.getHours();
  var greeting;

  if (hrs < 12) greeting = "Good Morning";
  else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17) greeting = "Good Afternoon";
  else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24) greeting = "Good Evening";

  return (
    <div className="nav-container">
        <p className="greeting">{greeting}</p>
        <Date />
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: Hi Leslie, welcome to SO, when I run this code it seems to work fine. Can you create a [mcve] ?

Comment: Maybe you are using an old browser?

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you! I'm not really sure why because I was working a few days ago.

Comment: Mikkel, I'm using chrome. I believe it's up to date but I'll double check

Comment: In your latest code you show that `Date` is not the built in Date object, but some file you're importing. Can you show us that file? Alternatively, if you mean to use normal dates, delete that import.

Comment: @NicholasTower Yea, thats just a component that renders the day, date, and time. It's in a separate component so I can move it around independently, not sure where I want to use it yet. I'll show it to you

Comment: Then that's your problem. Delete the import.

Comment: I think, when you say "new Date()", it is taking your custom component and not the Javascript "Date" class. Can you try renaming your React Component to different name instead of <Date />?

Comment: @NicholasTower That was it! I'll change the name of that import. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @SivaKondapiVenkata Yup, that was it lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not use Date as `component` and Date as `Date` object

please change

```
import Date from "./Date";
 ...
<Date />
```

to

```
import Date as ObjDate from "./Date";
 ...
<ObjDate />
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to recreate the issue. Copied the piece of code from your example and here is the result:

https://codepen.io/tural-ali/pen/vYEeaRK

```
var date = new Date();
var hrs = date.getHours();
alert(hrs);
```

It works totally fine.

That means it's something related to your imports:

```
import Date from "./Date";
```

is the line that causes the error. Try to create alias for this import as:

```
import Date as DateObject from "./Date";
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. It was working for me as well a few days ago but now I'm getting the error. Someone just helped me, it was one of my imports

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! My upvotes are recorded but unfortunately not displayed yet.